# iframe won't center on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, iframe

My iFrame isn't centering in mobile. I have to define the width at 1250px because otherwise it only shows a sliver of the iFrame on desktop. I really need the black edges to be off of the screen on mobile...

http://www.howlatthemoon.com/birthday-parties-chicago

(I have to use the iFrame because my CMS is so out of date, it won't work with this code. I would just hide the black gradient i have on the edges, but the CMS doesn't respond to media queries)

```
iframe, object, embed {
 max-width: 100%;
}

#midslide {
    clear:right;
margin-top: -47px;
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
width:1250px;
height:338px;
}


.center{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
width: 100%; 
}



<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="midslide" align="middle" src="http://www.howlatthemoon.com/images/howl/landing/birthday-parties/slider2.html"></iframe>
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
#midslide {
    clear: right;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-top: -47px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No luck, it won't center that way and it didn't work in mobile anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the css, it's your left/right black gradient image.
The left one to be specific, it pushes all the slider to the right, so whatever you do in your css, you still end up with a left black mask image.
There's nothing wrong to have this, And I can see why you need this for your desktop visitors, but you can do it in a better way, not to include them in your in-line HTML code, you can set left/right padding/border to the slider div. Even if you do want to embed them like the way they are now, do it right. 
Apparently the left image is outside the slider while the right one is wrapped inside. That's the problem you have.
Good luke man, hope this helps.